# MYSQL returning the max value per group

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a bit problem returning the max value of a group using mysql

this is my columns

```
     id | date           | time     | tran
--------+----------------+----------+----------
      1 | 2014/03/31     | 17:23:00 | 1234
      1 | 2014/03/31     | 17:24:00 | 3467
      2 | 2014/03/31     | 17:26:00 | 2345
```

My query

```
SELECT id, max(date), MAX(time) , tran
FROM table
GROUP BY id
```

RESULT

```
     id | date           | time     | tran
--------+----------------+----------+----------
      1 | 2014/03/31     | 17:26:00 | 1234
      2 | 2014/03/31     | 17:24:00 | 2345
```

Expected answer should be

```
     id | date           | time     | tran
--------+----------------+----------+----------
      1 | 2014/03/31     | 17:26:00 | 3467
      2 | 2014/03/31     | 17:24:00 | 2345
```

Comment: `tran = 3467` belongs to `id = 2` so why do you expect it to be shown for `id = 1` (in your "expected answer should be)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by using self join on the maxima from same table

```
SELECT t.* FROM
Table1 t
JOIN (
SELECT id, max(date) date, MAX(time) time , tran
FROM Table1
GROUP BY id) t2
ON(t.id=t2.id AND t.date=t2.date AND t.time=t2.time)
```

### [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a75d9/1)

There may be differences between maxima of date and time so you should use a single field for saving date and time for you current schema this one is optimal

```
SELECT t.* FROM
Table1 t
JOIN (
SELECT id, 
  max(concat(date,' ',time)) `date_time`

FROM Table1
GROUP BY id) t2
ON(t.id=t2.id AND (concat(t.date,' ',t.time))=t2.date_time )
```

### [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a75d9/4)

Answer (score 3):

There is a great article on this theme which a read every time i am facing your problem. You might want to c[heck it](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/)

Applying to you query, this will look like:

```
   SELECT *
   FROM `table`
   WHERE (
      SELECT count(*) FROM `table` AS t
      WHERE `t`.`id` = `table`.`id` AND `t`.`tran` <= `table`.`tran`
   ) < 2;
```

Best thing i like about this way, you can easily get top 2, 3 or any number of rows you need

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the GREATEST() function:

```
SELECT GREATEST(field1, field2);
```

If you want to get the absolute maximum in mysql from all the rows, then you may want to use the following query:

```
SELECT GREATEST(MAX(field1), MAX(field2));
```

Please let me know if it helped

Comment: its still returning the wrong result if the column trans_time is getting the max value but the column tran is still returning 1234 it should be 3467

Comment: try adding order by at the end, "ORDER BY trans desc"

Answer (score 0):

Your Query:

```
SELECT id, max(date), MAX(time) , tran
FROM table
GROUP BY id
```

Now, you should use MAX(tran) and GROUP BY tran in your query to get the expected result.

Otherwise, you'll obviously end up with tran = 1234 since your query is only fetching those rows where date is MAX(date) and time is MAX(time) but tran value is normal tran value. Plus you are doing GROUP BY id whereas it must GROUP BY the maximum value of tran.

So, your query should be changed to something like this:

```
SELECT MAX(date), MAX(time), MAX(tran)
FROM table
GROUP BY tran
```

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted seconds after being upvoted? :(